# Creating new partition with label in Rust

Tags: linux, rust, filesystems, disk-partitioning

I'm trying to partition the disk on my Linux machine using Rust.

To format and create new partition I'm using `sgdisk` utility.

```
#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
pub struct Drives {
    system: PathBuf,
    home: Option<PathBuf>,
}

impl Drives {

  fn create_partitions(&self) -> Result<()> {

  cmd!("sgdisk", "--new=0:0:+256MiB --typecode=0:ef00 -c 0:\"efi\"", &self.system).run().context("Failed to create EFI partition")?;
  Ok(())
  }
 }
```

The command succeeds with creating a new partition, but unfortunately the label is missing.

```
sgdisk -p /dev/sda
...
Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1            2048          526335   256.0 MiB   8300
```

The `cmd!` macro comes from `duct` crate which passes the content to `std::process::Command` underneath. Even if I directly call the external process I don't get the partition labeled.

I suppose the issue is probably with passing the String to `sgdisk` expecting **zero** terminated ASCII string. If I call the same command in shell script it works.

Comment: Then add `\0` after efi?

Comment: @hellow I tried adding \0, but without success.

Comment: Seems I've been looking into this the wrong way as I had similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55865024/generating-iso-with-xorriso. Turns out all I have to do is split the argument. That means pass it as `cmd!("sgdisk", "--new=0:0:+256MiB", "--typecode=0:ef00", "-c", "0:efi", &self.system)` and it works like charm.

Comment: @phodina Yup, you need to separate the arguments. Otherwise the whole argument is wrapped in a single string.