# Generating ISO with xorriso

Tags: rust, archlinux

I'm trying to remaster ISO image of Archlinux using Rust.

To get the ISO I need to run `xorriso` utility as external command using `duct` crate.

However I get these (strange) errors (doesn't happen if I run it from shell script):

```
cmd!("sudo","xorriso", "-x", "-as mkisofs", "-iso-level 3", "-full-iso9660-filenames", iso_label, eltorito_boot, eltorito_cat, "-no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table", isohybrid, "-eltorito-alt-boot", efi, "-no-emul-boot -isohybrid-gpt-basdat", output, root).run().context("Failed to create new ISO")?

xorriso : FAILURE : Not a known command:  '-as mkisofs'

xorriso : FAILURE : Not a known command:  '-iso-level 3'

xorriso : FAILURE : Not a known command:  '-full-iso9660-filenames'

xorriso : FAILURE : Not a known command:  '-volid "ARCH_201904"'

xorriso : FAILURE : Not a known command:  '-eltorito-boot "isolinux/isolinux.bin"'

xorriso : FAILURE : Not a known command:  '-eltorito-catalog "isolinux/boot.cat"'

xorriso : FAILURE : Not a known command:  '-no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table'
...
```

Comment: might be because of the sudo. Can you try it without it (you may of course get a not perrmited)

Comment: Should be `"-as", "mkisofs"` instead of `"-as mkisofs"`, should be `"-iso-level", "3"` instead of `"-iso-level 3"` etc etc, please that basic

Comment: @Stargateur Thanks. Splitting it as individual arguments solves the issue.